# Ball bouncing elastically off a moving wall

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Consider a ball moving in one dimmension which bounces off a fixed wall. If the collision is elastic, the rebounds with the same velocity as it hit the wall.

Now suppose the wall is accelerating with some acceleration $a$. Assuming the collision remains elastic, how can we calculate the rebound velocity.

Comment: If the collision is elastic, it rebounds with the same *relative velocity*.

Comment: Please show your attempt to do the calculation. The rebound velocity depends on the relative velocities at impact, not the acceleration of the wall.

Comment: Well I guess the question is in which frame is the kinetic energy conserved.

Comment: The relative velocity is the same in all frames of reference.

Comment: Well my point is iff the kinetic energy is conseved in the frame of the moving wall, then the result is obvious. But how do know that this is the case?

Comment: This is kinda related to Fermi acceleration (which is more of an exercise in relativistic kinematics). Should be mostly conservation of energy & momentum with care in frame jumping.

Comment: Use the frame in which the collision is elastic. By definition an elastic collision conserves kinetic energy.